# CakePHP containables - Working backwards

Tags: php, cakephp, contain

I have a database of Clients. Each Client can have many Contracts. Each Contract contains many Invoices.

In the Invoice view, i'm trying to display the client_name, but I only have the contract_id with which to link the Invoice to the Client.

I have tried the following, but I can only retrieve the Invoice and Contract details when debugging out the array:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Invoice->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Invoice->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid invoice'));
    }
    $payment = $this->Invoice->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Invoice.id' => $id
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Contract' => array(
                 'Client'
             ) 

        )
    ));
    $this->set('Invoice', $this->Invoice->read(null, $id));
}
```

Comment: what does <pre><?php print_r( $payment ); ?></pre> return?

Comment: An array containing 'Invoice' and 'Contract' arrays respectively. The Contract array contains the 'client_id', which i would like to use to grab the 'client_name'

Comment: Have you added "belongs to" in Invoice and Contract models?

Comment: Yes, Invoice belongs to Contract, Contract belongs to Client, in their respective models.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I simply increased the recursion level inside the AppModel to 2, thus grabbing all associative data. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't increase the recursion level. It's bad practice. Chances are you just weren't using containable correctly. Did you have public $actsAs = array('Containable'); in your app model?

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the tip, and yes I have that in my AppModel.